# Exception reason in Apple Crashlogs not (no longer?) present

Tags: ios, exception, crash-log

I used to view Apple Crashlogs which had an exception reason included. These days though I can no longer see these, e.g. here:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x1843fbd38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:166)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x183910528 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreFoundation                      0x1843fbc80 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116 (NSException.m:141)
3   Foundation                          0x184e0e084 -[__NSConcreteURLComponents initWithString:] + 116 (NSURL.m:2035)
```

This looks very much like a `nil` parameter, but without the exception message it's guesswork.

Any idea why these are no longer present in crashlogs?

Comment: Have you tried Exception breakpoint and Error breakpoint from Xcode?

Comment: The thing is… I can't duplicate the crash, that's why my only chance is to inspect the crash logs from other people's devices.